# Xamarin Custom control not showing in toolbox

Tags: xamarin.forms

Even though I have marked my custom Xamarin forms control with the following. It is still not showing in the Xamarin forms toolbox any reason as to why that may note I am using a .netstandard shared Libary to house my controls inside a NuGet if that makes any difference.

It is a progress bar and I want the end-user to be able to drag it into the xaml. In the same way the entry textbox works.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component is within the project, you can have them automatically added to the toolbox. Please check this setting: `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Windows Forms Designer`, and enable the `AutoToolboxPopulate` option.

If it's in a separate solution, you can build the control library, and drag and drop on the toolbox to add the components.

Note: Remember to compile the project before looking the toolbox . If you haven't compiled it, it won't be in the list even with this option enabled.

Comment: i have done this but still wont appear its a .net standard 2.0 project does that make a differece

Comment: the controls are still refusing to show up for me even thugh that is ticked their built and in a nuget package so i referenced the dll direclty and stil didnt work